# How can I add an extra admin column showing the word-count of a page or post?

Tags: wp-admin

For the 'view all' screens which list posts (edit-post) and pages (edit-page) how can I add an extra admin column with the word count of individual posts/pages?

Having previously used the 'admin columns' plugin, and aware of alternatives, I'm wondering if there's a simpler filter/function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really difficult. Manage columns in posts list you can with 2 hooks: `manage_posts_columns`, `manage_posts_custom_column`

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'wordcount_column');
function wordcount_column($columns) {
    $columns['wordcount'] = 'Word count';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'show_wordcount');
function show_wordcount($name) 
{
    global $post;
    switch ($name) 
    {
        case 'wordcount':
            $wordcount = YOUR_WORD_COUNT_VALUE
            echo $wordcount;
    }
}
```

Then you only need calc word count after save_post to post_meta and show counts in columns.

```
add_action('save_post', function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( strip_shortcodes($post->post_content) ) );

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wordcount', $word_count);
}, 10, 3);
```

Related [gist](https://gist.github.com/antonlukin/dd22530f180300e67385025568521081)

Another way is to calc words count on-the-fly.

```
function post_word_count($post_id) {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( strip_shortcodes($content) ) );
    return $word_count;
}
```

Related [gist](https://gist.github.com/imelgrat/ef8acd5583245d4573294f7df352a754)

But I suggest to calc words only once on `save_post` hook. Note that better save it in post_meta starting with [underscore](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields)

For example: `_wordcount`

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, your suggestion of 'calc words only once on save_post hook' differs from the on-the-fly code. I don't know enough to do this, so if you've more info I'll be grateful. (And if you don't have more info, that's of course ok - thanks again for helping.)

Comment: I've updated the post. Feed free to ask questions

Comment: thanks, again. With increasing brain-fade (at this rate I'll probably soon struggle to read/write/understand my own name), I'm not smart enough to understand how to use the revised code ('YOUR_WORD_COUNT_VALUE' has me immediately perplexed).

Comment: I've made the gist with final solution for you https://gist.github.com/antonlukin/dd22530f180300e67385025568521081

Comment: Thanks. Hugely appreciated. I re-saved all posts to add the count.

Comment: You are welcome. Accept the answer, please