# Just how 'expensive' is this function?

Tags: wp-admin

Having added a 'word count' admin column, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917725/update-all-wordpress-posts)  function from elsewhere on Stack to resave all posts and thus populate the word count (the wordcount function calculates on post-save).

With just a couple hundred posts/pages on a dedicated server with almost no public traffic, I thought I'd be alright to `'numberposts' => -1'` and update all at once.

Seems not, as doing so sent the machine into a tizzy requiring a quick *"what do I now?"* call to support - who reported *"there were many Apache child processes running, leading the server to an average load of 120%"* and disabled `wp-cron.php`.

I'd already commented-out the function, so assume that once-started the processes continued in an Automattic-induced meltdown. (Perhaps not - I don't pretend to understand this, and am happy to be educated.)

Three questions:

1. I'm safe to re-enable `wp-cron.php`?
2. Next time I'm tempted to use this, I shouldn't use `'numberposts'
   => -1'`. Perhaps stick to something like `'numberposts' => 10'`?
3. What upset the server - was it the word-count, or just re-saving
   two hundred posts?

The word count code from [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277870/how-can-i-add-an-extra-admin-column-showing-the-word-count-of-a-page-or-post) is below:

```
add_action('save_post', function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    $word_count = explode(" ", strip_shortcodes($post->post_content));
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wordcount', count($word_count));
}, 10, 3);
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', function($columns){
    $columns['wordcount'] = 'Word count';
    return $columns;
});
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', function($name) {
    global $post;

    if($wordcount === '')
         $wordcount = 'not counted';
    if($name === 'wordcount')
        echo $wordcount;
 });
```

Day-after update...

In response to requests I'm adding the 'update all posts' code to which I originally linked.

```
function example_hide(){
$my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):
wp_update_post( $my_post );
endforeach;
}
add_action('init','example_hide');
```

I first ran the update with 'numberposts' => 10' and it completed in seconds - hence my decision to switch to -1.

Comment: Please provide the code you used

Comment: Counting words shouldn't be expensive. I have heavier tasks, done on a shared hosting that take less than 30 seconds to run, unless there is something in your code that we are not aware of.

Comment: @kero... Thanks. I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @Jack Johansson... Thanks. My updated post contains the code.

Comment: This is your complete code? I don't see any schedule/transient stuff in there, so you should be save to re-enable wp-cron.php. As for performance, this isn't really heavy code, so I don't see why it should crash your server

Comment: if you edit the question to include all parts of the code, I promise an answer. deal? ;) (the answer will not make much sense without people actually seeing the code it refers to)

Comment: Seems fine to me. Nothing to lose sleep about.

Comment: Please add the code you used to update all your posts.

Comment: @kero... Thanks for the re-assurance, although I'm still wondering why the issue happened. I'd previously ran the update with 'numberposts' => 10' and it completed in seconds - hence my decision to switch to -1. From the little I know, I wonder whether each attempt to access site pages while the update was in progress caused wp-cron to restart the process and thus overload the server.

Comment: @Michael... Thanks. I'm still wondering why the issue happened. I'd previously ran the update with 'numberposts' => 10' and it completed in seconds - hence my decision to switch to -1. From the little I know, I wonder whether each attempt to access site pages while the update was in progress caused wp-cron to restart the process and thus overload the server.

Comment: @Mark...Thanks. I didn't include requested code because it's easy accessible on the linked Stack page, but in response to your request I'll update my original post accordingly.

Comment: @inarilo... Please note my comment to Mark Kaplun.

Comment: I've been reluctant to add so many comments, but politeness suggests a notified response is appropriate, and as-best-I-can understand the reply process requires a single @ per comment.

Comment: you used the code as given. which is not applicable to your case, you are just fetching the posts and putting them back as they were. also a one time update should not run on init which runs on every page load. - edit: just saw Mark's answer

Comment: @inarilo... Thanks. Although I'm 'just putting them back as they were', the purpose of the resave was to trigger the 'count'. In response to the responses of yourself and Mark, I'm reading more about 'init' - to be honest, I hadn't even considered it and probably (because I was working on what I thought to be an admin function) thought of it as 'admin_init'.

Comment: that's an unnecessary DB operation for each post, simplest way would be to create a temporary private page, get all posts, and use the 2 same lines you run on save_post in a post loop. then delete the page, since it's a one time thing.

Answer (score 1):

rule of thumb, never do anything that results in DB write from the front end. Even better if you can create an admin page in which the operation is triggered (even if it just starts an AJAx based process).

Your problem here is with hooking on an inappropriate hook. You hooked on `init` which means that for **each** request the code to change all your posts is being run. Since this is a heavy operation it overloaded you DB and therefor your server. I am not sure why cron was singled out here.

As an additional note, your save handler is not great, you should make sure you are handling the post type you want and not revisions or auto saves.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered 'never do anything that results in DB write from the front end'... as noted in a comment above, at the time I was working on admin stuff and likely unthinkingly read it as 'admin_init'. I'm now reading more to understand better. I triggered it by reloading a page-listing screen, and wasn't aware of wpcron (and that it loads on every page access) until it was disabled by the server support team. So presumably 'add_action('init','example_hide');' loads on every page access - would changing it to 'add_action('init','example_hide');' load only on admin access?

Comment: On your point of 'make sure you are handling the post type you want and not revisions or auto saves', what should I therefore change to exclude 'revisions/auto-saves'? And, just to clarify, the intent was to run the function just once per post_type, to add the count, and then disable it by commenting-out.

Comment: wp-cron do not load on every page access. it is possible that cron process failed to end or even to execute at all which was the reason for cron being triggered so many times. As for just changing the hook, why to do it, be defensive and make explicit admin pages when you need to do such a thing, no reason to be in a position where it can be triggered "randomally" with no explicit user action

Comment: as for checking for revisions - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_post_revision/ can be used. You want to avoid it as generaly there is no meta associated with revisions, same with autosaves https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference /wp_is_post_autosave which might override meta values without the post being saved. And obviously, if the count is held only for posts and not for pages, why to calculate it for pages?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, appreciated. Looks like I've some more learning to do.